# List style not working

Tags: html, css

When i apply list style to un-ordered list, the bullet is appearing only when i refresh the browser button otherwise not appearing.

Css:

```
.span9 ul li
{
 list-style: disc outside none;
 margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Html:

```
<div  class="span9">
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine here without changing your code, what wrong with this!

http://jsfiddle.net/NpQs5/

```
.span9 ul li { list-style: disc outside none; margin-left: 1em; }
```